# Code.org AppLabs: I am unable to get a specific whether condition on and display it on the screen

Tags: javascript, code.org

I'm working on this weather app, but I ran into a problem where I am unable to get the specific whether condition from the data set onto the screen. It always displays the whether condition for one of the cities, but not the others. I need some help on this if possible, and could be a big help if you point out any mistakes I have made.

```js
//The variables
var low = getColumn("Daily Weather", "Low Temperature");
var high = getColumn("Daily Weather", "High Temperature");
var city = getColumn("Daily Weather", "City");
var icon = getColumn("Daily Weather", "Icon");
var condition = getColumn("Daily Weather", "Main Condition");
var forecastNum = getColumn("Daily Weather", "Forecast Number");
var id = 0;
//filtered variables
var todayLow = [];
var todayHigh = [];
var todayCondition = [];
var todayIcon = [];

onEvent("locationDropdown", "change", function( ) {
  if (getText("locationDropdown") == "Anchorage, Alaska") {
    id = 1;
  } else if ((getText("locationDropdown") == "Fairbanks, Alaska")) {
    id = 6;
  } else if ((getText("locationDropdown") == "Denver/Boulder, Colorado")) {
    id = 16;
  } else if ((getText("locationDropdown") == "Chicago, Illinois")) {
    id = 31;
  } else if ((getText("locationDropdown") == "Des Moines, Iowa")) {
    id = 56;
  } else if ((getText("locationDropdown") == "Goodland, Kansas")) {
    id = 66;
  } else if ((getText("locationDropdown") == "Louisville, Kentucky")) {
    id = 86;
  } else {
    id = 96;
  }
});

onEvent("conditionButton", "click", function( ) {
  updateScreen();
  setScreen("screen2");
});
onEvent("conditionButton1", "click", function( ) {
  updateScreen();
  setScreen("screen2");
});
onEvent("tempButton", "click", function( ) {
  updateScreen();
  setScreen("screen3");
});
onEvent("homeButton1", "click", function( ) {
  updateScreen();
  setScreen("screen1");
});
onEvent("homeButton2", "click", function( ) {
  updateScreen();
  setScreen("screen1");
});
onEvent("temperatureButton", "click", function( ) {
  updateScreen();
  setScreen("screen3");
});
function updateScreen() {
  var index = id;
  console.log(id);
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (forecastNum[i] == 1) {
      appendItem(todayLow, low[i]);
      appendItem(todayHigh, high[i]);
      appendItem(todayCondition, condition[i]);
      appendItem(todayIcon, icon[i]);
    }
  }
  setText("lowTemp", todayLow[1]);
  setText("highTemp", todayHigh[1]);
  setText("label2", todayCondition[1]);
  setProperty("image2", "image", todayIcon[1]);
  console.log(idNum);
  console.log(index);
  console.log(todayLow);
}
```

```html
=
```

Comment: Your code example doesn't work. 1. The html part only has a `=` 2. You probably forgot to load dependency scripts because the error in the console says: "ReferenceError: getColumn is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

```js
function updateScreen() {
  var index = id;
  console.log(id);
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (forecastNum[i] == 1) {
      appendItem(todayLow, low[i]);
      appendItem(todayHigh, high[i]);
      appendItem(todayCondition, condition[i]);
      appendItem(todayIcon, icon[i]);
    }
  }
  setText("lowTemp", todayLow[1]);
  setText("highTemp", todayHigh[1]);
  setText("label2", todayCondition[1]);
  setProperty("image2", "image", todayIcon[1]);
  console.log(idNum);
  console.log(index);
  console.log(todayLow);
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this is where the problem is. Whenever you want to update the screen, it only updates it to whatever is index 1 inside `todayLow` `todayHigh` `todayCondition`  and `todayIcon` arrays.  Instead of putting "1" for the array of these, you should find a way to automatically change the value based on whatever dropdown the user selected. Also, not really a bad thing that you did, but instead of doing:

```js
onEvent("locationDropdown", "change", function( ) {
  if (getText("locationDropdown") == "Anchorage, Alaska") {
    id = 1;
  } else if ((getText("locationDropdown") == "Fairbanks, Alaska")) {
    id = 6;
  } else if ((getText("locationDropdown") == "Denver/Boulder, Colorado")) {
    id = 16;
  } else if ((getText("locationDropdown") == "Chicago, Illinois")) {
    id = 31;
  } else if ((getText("locationDropdown") == "Des Moines, Iowa")) {
    id = 56;
  } else if ((getText("locationDropdown") == "Goodland, Kansas")) {
    id = 66;
  } else if ((getText("locationDropdown") == "Louisville, Kentucky")) {
    id = 86;
  } else {
    id = 96;
  }
});
```

You could have also done:

```js
onEvent("locationDropdown", "change", function( ) {
  switch (getText("locationDropdown")) {
    case "Anchorage, Alaska":
      id = 1;
    break;
    case "Fairbanks, Alaska":
      id = 6;
    break;
    case "Denver/Boulder, Colorado":
      id = 16;
    break;
    case "Chicago Illinois":
      id = 31;
    break;
    case "Des Moines, Iowa":
      id = 56;
    break;
    case "Goodland, Kansas":
      id = 66;
    break;
    case "Louisville, Kentucky":
      id = 86;
    break;
    default:
      id = 96;
    break;
  }
});
```

The `switch statement` is very useful in code because it saves time because you no longer have to write `getText("locationDropdown")` for every else if statement you write.

Anyways, I hope my answer helped at least a little. I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: Instead of a switch the question owner could also use a hash map/lookup table: https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/switch-case-if-else-or-a-lookup-map-a-study-case-de1c801d944